# When is module rendered in drupal?

Tags: caching, drupal, module

I am a newcomer in Drupal, and I want to make a custom module in Drupal8.
I have developed the module, but there are some problems to solve.

The module displays GET parameter value when a page containing the module is shown to users.

For example, I connect with http://localhost/drupal/?keyword=banana and the module displays "banana".

But after the above, when I connect with http://localhost/drupal/?keyword=apple again, then the module displays "banana" too.

In other words, the module works well when the page containing the module is shown firstly and works wrong when I connect secondly, thirdly and so on.

I have tested some and build() method in the module is called only once.
So, I think that the module is rendered only once when I connect to the page and can't be rendered after the first.

Also, I think that it can be the problem related to cache, but I set admin/configuration/performance/cache to "no-cache".

I am not sure that it is possible to display "apple" after "banana" is displayed by the module.

Please help me and let me know more details...

Thanks.

Comment: take a look https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: Thanks for your care. i am doing with the module on drupal8. but there will be some problems. if the module works well, in other words the development is done, and I set cache for my site, how will the module work? can you make sure that it will work well as same as during development? I mean that you think my problems will be related to cache, so you suggest to disable it during development. but how about enabling cache after development is done?

Comment: I can't set site: mode to development. I have installed drupal console 1.0.0 alpha1 and  rc26, but CommandNotFoundException occured. There are only 4 modes available such as new, install, import:local debug for site:mode. I can't progress it anymore

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible solutions depending on your constraints: disable the cache for this particular page, or use routing wildcards.

You can disable the cache on a particular page by using the page cache kill switch service, which you trigger like this in your controller:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

This will disable the cache just for this particular request, so you won't get the effect of seeing stale content.

A better solution, if possible, is to use routing parameters instead of your GET parameters. This will allow your separate URLs (for example page/banana, page/apple etc.) to be cached and still show the contents you'd like them to. For example, in your module.routing.yml file:

```
mymodule.route:
  path: '/path/{parameter}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::page'
    _title: 'My Module Page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The {parameter} parameter can then be accessed in your controller like so:

```
public function page($parameter) {
  return ['#markup' => $parameter];
}
```

More information: https://www.drupal.org/node/2186285